# Cant play a song using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, media-player, android-mediaplayer

Im having some problems playing a simple song (stored in the external SD) using MediaPlayer API. I really dont know what Im doing wrong, cause I havent seen the code error in any other questions and using the developer I havent found it either.

The error Im getting is this:

```
08-25 00:20:49.514: D/MediaPlayer(26764): mPlayerID = 94
08-25 00:20:49.519: E/MediaPlayer(26764): error (1, -2147483648)
08-25 00:20:49.597: E/MediaPlayer(26764): Error (1,-2147483648)
```

AudioActivity.java

```
public class AudioActivity extends Activity{

    Audio audioPlayer;

    public AudioActivity(){

        audioPlayer = new Audio();

    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Set of view where videos and the listView (is there is any) will appear
        setContentView(R.layout.audio_player);      

        Button play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.playButton);

        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "song";
                audioPlayer.loadFile(path);
                audioPlayer.prepare();
                audioPlayer.play();
            }
        });

        Button pauseResume = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pauseButton);

        pauseResume.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                audioPlayer.pause();
            }
        });

        Button stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopButton);

        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                audioPlayer.stop();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Audio.class

```
public class Audio {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    String pathSong;

    public Audio(){

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

                Log.d("Error", "Arg1: " + arg1 + ".Arg2: " + arg2);
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                return false;
            }

        });
    }

    public void loadFile(String path){

        try {
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }

    public void prepare(){
        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(){

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();    
            }
        });
    }

    public void stop(){

        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    public void pause(){

        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    public int getDuration(){

        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(){

        return mediaPlayer;
    }


    public TrackInfo[] getTrackInfo(){

        return mediaPlayer.getTrackInfo();
    }
}
```

Any idea? Why the code (1, -2147483648) doesnt appear anywhere? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use constructors in classes which extend `Activity`. Get rid of your constructor and move `audioPlayer = new Audio();` into the `onCreate(...)` method after the line where you call `setContentView(...)`.

Comment: I think you are missing the file's extension, you path file name doesnt have extension, you just say song.

Comment: Yes, I added the extension and it works!